# elasticsearch custom score formula

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a site that has a search using elasticsearch.
There is a rule that I need to implement:

the site is a search engine for women's products
but we have some stores that will pay to have their products appear on the site
we need to give priority to products from paying stores

We think the formula would be this:

- store that is a customer (higher weight)
- number of product views

Is there a way to use function_score to solve this?
and display the products randomly? (without blocking the list with only products from paying stores)

Comment: Hi, your formula is not clear. Could you provide more details as to what you want to observe ? Maybe an exemple or an actual math formula

Comment: I have a product search page. I need to increase the score of products of some stores (paid). I need to increase the score using the updated date from product too.